# Custom React Hook that renders a ReactNode asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I'm implementing a text editor whose JSX can be a little slow to compute. While the JSX loads, the whole page freezes. I'm trying to develop a Hook that lets the JSX lag behind the text so I don't have lag spike issues.

Obviously this requires rendering the JSX asynchronously. I also want to always use the most recent version of the JSX that's been computed, without computing EVERY single in-between JSX value.

Here's a demo of my Hook so far. It all goes inside a FunctionComponent. I think it's complete, but I can't figure out why useEffect gets called over and over again and enters an infinite loop. Ideas?

```
  const slowComponent = async () => {
    let i = 0
    // while (i < 1000000000) i++
    return <div>This component takes some time to load!</div>
  }

  const ref = useRef<{
    isComputing: boolean,
    todoSlowComponent: (() => Promise<React.ReactNode>) | null,
  }>({
    isComputing: false,
    todoSlowComponent: null,
  })


  const [most_recent_slow_component, set_most_recent_slow_component] = useState<React.ReactNode>(null)

  const computeInBG = async (slowComponent: () => Promise<React.ReactNode>) => {

    ref.current.todoSlowComponent = slowComponent
    if (ref.current.isComputing)
      return

    let req = ref.current.todoSlowComponent
    ref.current.isComputing = true
    ref.current.todoSlowComponent = null


    const awaitedComponent = await req()


    ref.current.isComputing = false
    if (ref.current.todoSlowComponent !== null) 
      console.log('THIS CAN ACTUALLY PRINT DUE TO ASYNC BEHAVIOR!!!!')
    if (ref.current.todoSlowComponent)
      computeInBG(ref.current.todoSlowComponent)


    set_most_recent_slow_component(awaitedComponent)

  }

  useEffect(() => { console.log('USE EFFECT'); computeInBG(slowComponent) })



  return <>/*... */most_recent_slow_component</>
```

Answer (score 1):

your useEffect do not have any dependency array. So it is going to call again if any changes happen in the component. Make it dependent on some value for example,

```
useEffect(() => {
  computeInBG(slowComponent);
}, [text]);
```

Comment: It's still getting called every time I press a key, making it pointless. Any idea why computeInBG, which is an async function, isn't computing in the background????

Comment: When do you want computeInBG to be called? What is the trigger?